# Correct place to set $BIBINPUTS environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, emacs, latex

If I set the `$BIBINPUTS` environment varibale in my `.zshrc`, it is recognized by `emacs-reftex` (via `emacsclient`), if I start emacs from my `zsh` commandline.

However if I start using the menubar or `gmrun` it doesn't knot this variable. So where is the correct place to set for the whole user environment?

If there are several alternatives, let me know. Also if it changed between differend ubuntu-versions.

**Edit:**

I have tried to set it in `~/.pam_environment` like

```
BSTINPUTS=.:/home/myuser/BiBTeX/:$BSTINPUTS
BIBINPUTS=.:/home/myuser/BiBTeX/:$BIBINPUTS
```

but it seems to have no effect (even after rebooting) and is not listed via `printenv`.

I am currently using ubuntu natty + gdm + xmonad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting it in `~/.profile` and then logging out and back in? Any variables you set in that file should get set when you log in via either X or ssh/console. If setting it in there does not work, it is a bug, and you should open a bug report about it.

Comment: Before I asked the question I tried it, but it didn't work (despite the fact, that they were listed via `printenv`). However emacsclient didn't know them. After your suggestion I tried it again (and rebooted instead of just logging out and in).